# Spark SQL return a new Dataframe from withColumnRenamed, does it take up the memory?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I already have the dataframe `Person(name:String, age:Int)` and I want to change its column name to `Person(X: String, Y:Int)` in order to do a join with another dataframe recursively to get new results.

I am confused: if I do this name change, will it take extra memory or just refer to the original dataframe?

Where I don't understand is if the renamed dataframe take up the memory that the table exactly is or it is just a reference to the dataframe without renaming?

Comment: Case classes are immutable. Can you share some code on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Dataframes are immutable. It will return a new dataframe when you'll invoke `withColumnRenamed` on it.